# CoreBluetooth can only accept commands while in the connected state

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-peripheral

`[CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBPeripheral: 0x281310820, identifier = 75450BB1-97A7-5648-38FD-B27572F19EDD, name = ESP32 test, state = disconnected> can only accept commands while in the connected state`

That's the error CoreBluetooth gives me when I try to

`peripheral.discoverServices([CBUUID(string: "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b")])`

Does anyone has any clue about what's going on?

Here's the didDiscover delegate:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    var peripheralName: String!
    if let name = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
        peripheralName = name
    }
    else {
        peripheralName = "Unknown"
    }
    
    if(advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] != nil) {
        //print(advertisementData)
        let Ids: [CBUUID] = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] as! [CBUUID]
        if(Ids.count == 1) {
            print(Ids[0])
            let newPeripheral = Peripheral(id: peripherals.count, name: peripheralName, rssi: RSSI.intValue)
            //print(newPeripheral)
            /*
            if let services = peripheral.services {
                for service in services {
                    print("servizio")
                    //peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([CBUUID(string: "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b")], for: service)
                }
            }*/
            if(accepted_services.contains(Ids[0].uuidString)) {
                print(newPeripheral)
                peripherals.append(newPeripheral)
                peripheral.delegate = self
                peripheral.discoverServices([CBUUID(string: "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b")])
                //peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([CBUUID(string: "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8")], for: <#CBService#>)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I now tried to connect first to the peripheral BUT there is another error:

`[CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: Cancelling connection for unused peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x2829e01e0, identifier = 75450BB1-97A7-5648-38FD-B27572F19EDD, name = ESP32 test, state = connecting>, Did you forget to keep a reference to it?`

this is the actual code:

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String:Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("scoperto peripheral")
    myCentral.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Core Bluetooth : Getting API MISUSE Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338767/ios-core-bluetooth-getting-api-misuse-warning)

Comment: that's the power on state problem, when you try to connect while the bluetooth is off. Mine problem it's different

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible for holding a reference to the CBPeripheral somewhere. That's what the message is telling you ("Did you forget to keep a reference to it?") You're creating a `Peripheral` (which I assume is a custom struct or class), but it only has the name, not the CBPeripheral. That means that at the end of `didDiscover`, the CBPeripheral isn't being referenced by anything and it's released.

Comment: Thanks! Now seems to work. I added this variable at start:
public var strong_reference: [CBPeripheral] = [CBPeripheral]()
and when I receive the CBPeripheral I save it. Thanks a lot. I don't know why it does work. Now it calls the didDiscoverServices and the didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor, but doesn't see any characteristic. That's strange.
Thanks again!

Comment: If Rob's answer solved your question you should consider accepting it.